# Best known Margulis constants?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, 3-manifolds

A Margulis number for a hyperbolic $n$-manifold $M=\mathbb{H}^n/\Gamma$ is a number $\epsilon>0$ such that for each $x\in\mathbb{H}^n$ the group generated by the elements in $\Gamma$ which move $x$ less than distance $\epsilon$ is elementary.
The Margulis constant for hyperbolic $n$-manifolds is the largest number $\epsilon(n)$ which is a Margulis number for every hyperbolic $n$-manifold.

Meyerhoff showed that $\epsilon(3) > 0.104$. ([Robert Meyerhoff. A lower bound for the volume of hyperbolic 3-manifolds. Canad. J. Math., 39(5):1038–1056, 1987.](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?extend=1&pg1=IID&s1=224643&vfpref=html&r=18&mx-pid=952231))

Shalen proved that 0.29 is a Margulis number for all but finitely many orientable hyperbolic 3-manifolds.  He also notes that experimental evidence suggests that $\epsilon(3) <0.616$ ([Peter Shalen. Topology and geometry in dimension three, 103–109, Contemp. Math., 560, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 2011](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=shalen&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=1&mx-pid=2866926))

Question 1: Is Meyerhoff's lower bound the best known lower bound for $\epsilon(3)$?

Question 2: What is known about the Margulis constants for higher dimensional hyperbolic manifolds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For question 2, the best known is due to Ruth Kellerhals (the answer is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5188175/2106991.pdf))

And for question 1, the latest (but, judging from [the math review](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5188175/2175884.pdf), not greatest) is Gehring/Martin.

Answer (score 8):

Results of [Culler and Shalen](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1135928) together with tameness, density, etc. imply that there exists a number $V$ such that if $M$ is a hyperbolic 3-manifold of volume $>V$, then the Margulis constant of $M$ is $\geq \log(3)$. This indicates that one ought to be able to compute the Margulis constant, making it an a priori trivial problem. To prove this, you take a sequence of 2-generator groups realizing the Margulis constant for manifolds with volume approaching $\infty$. In the limit, the Margulis constant is $>\log(3)$ by Culler-Shalen, so one concludes that there is some bound on volume for manifolds with Margulis constant $<\log(3)$.

**Addendum:** Recently [Yarmola (in joint work with Futer and Gabai) has announced](https://math.yale.edu/event/towards-margulis-constant-hyperbolic-3-manifolds) that they can show that the Margulis constant $\mu_3 > .5$.

Answer (score 4):

For Question 2: In addition to Kellerhals' lower bounds on $\epsilon(n)$, there is an absolute constant $C>0$ such that
$$
\epsilon(n)\le \frac{C}{\sqrt{n}},
$$
see Proposition 5.2 in

*Belolipetsky, Mikhail*, [**Hyperbolic orbifolds of small volume**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.5394), Jang, Sun Young (ed.) et al., Proceedings of the International Congress of Mathematicians (ICM 2014), Seoul, Korea, August 13–21, 2014. Vol. II: Invited lectures. Seoul: KM Kyung Moon Sa (ISBN 978-89-6105-805-6/hbk; 978-89-6105-803-2/set). 837-851 (2014). [ZBL1373.22017](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1373.22017).

The paper is also available in arXiv [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.5394.pdf).

Comment: link above seems broken, can I have a reference?

Comment: @Dinisaur: See the edit.